# Pass a QueryString as is in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc, query-string, .net-core-3.1

There is a method to pass the entire query string to another page using the a tag in .NET Core 3.1?

I tried this:

```
<a asp-action="VerifiedAll" asp-route="@Context.Request.QueryString.Value" 
   class="btn btn-manage">Verified All</a>
```

But I get an error, it could not create the href property using this

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 reached [End Of Life](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) last year. That means there's absolutely no support for it any more, not even security fixes. You shouldn't be writing any new code targeting 3.1 The current Long Term Support version is .NET 6, supported until November 2024

Comment: I know .NET Cose 3.1 has no support any more, but the company I'm working for decided to use this version for this project :(

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided?  Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

> There is a method to pass the entire query string to another page
> using the a tag in .NET Core 3.1? But I get an error, it could not
> create the href property using this

Based on your shared code and description its not very clear that what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Usually, [asp-route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route) attribute is used for creating a URL linking directly to a named route but for that your syntax were not correct. If you would like generate href than you should do as following:

```
<a asp-route="QueryStringValue" class="btn btn-success">Verified All</a>
```

[image]

Explanation:

```
public class QueyStringController : Controller
    {
        [Route("QueyString/VerifiedAll", Name="QueryStringValue")]
        public IActionResult VerifiedAll()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have used `QueryStringValue` as route name which I am passing in `asp-route` in  order to generate `<a> or href` tag.

But if you do otherwise, you would encounter following error.

[image]

How to pass query string in other page:

Actually, using numerous way, you can pass query string to another page on of the way you can implement is from controller redirection.

```
public IActionResult PassQueryString()
        {

          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { test="MyQueryStringvalue"});
        }
```

Above, redirection, will call Index action of Home controller and will pass Test query string with `MyQueryStringvalue` as value. You can now extract the value from your HttpContext.

```
<a asp-controller="QueyString" asp-action="VerifiedAll" asp-route-id="@Context.Request.QueryString.Value"
   class="btn btn-manage">Verified All</a>
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can have a [look at our official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route) here for [more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route)